# Stop function from auto firing on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, leaflet

I have a [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) map with some [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) functionalities inside my Ionic React app. I added lines (GeoJSON) with multiple features and added a popup to every feature, which can be accessed via a click on the feature. Inside this popup I want to have a button to copy parts of the popup to the clipboard. For copying I am using [Capacitor Clipboard](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/clipboard). The popup as well as the copying code is working, it is just not working the way I set it up inside the popup and I do not know how to get it going the way I want to...

The problem I am facing is that the function is called automatically as soon as the map is rendered and this causes the app to break down and shut down. But I only want the function to execute if the button in the popup is clicked if not nothing should be copied.

I found some similar question, but often the answer is to use `onClick={()=>{function()}}` but this did not work with the leaflet popup... And I assume there could be a better way triggering the `onclick="+writeToClipboard(part, id)+"`, but the stuff I tried did not work

```
function LeafletMap() {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

    const geoJsonRef = useRef();
  
    const writeToClipboard = async (part, id) => {
      var copyText = JSON.stringify(part.concat(id));
      await Clipboard.write({
        string: copyText
      });
    };
  
    const onEachClick = (info, layer) => {
      const part = info.properties.Objekt_ID
      const id = info.properties.FID_
  
      layer.bindPopup(
        "Objekt ID: <b>" + part + "</b><br>Abschnitt ID: <b>" + id + "</b><br><button onclick="+writeToClipboard(part, id)+">Copy to Clipboard</button>"
      );
      
      layer.on({ click: handleFeatureClick });
    };
  
    const handleFeatureClick = (e) => {
      if (!geoJsonRef.current) return;
      geoJsonRef.current.resetStyle();
  
      const layer = e.target;
  
      layer.setStyle({ color: "red" });
    };
  
  
    const displayMap = useMemo(
      () => (
        <MapContainer
          center={position}
          zoom={zoom}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
          whenCreated={setMap}>
          <LayersControl position="topright">
            <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="OpenStreetMap - Karte">
              <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              />
            </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
            <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Esri - Satellit">
              <TileLayer
                attribution='Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
                url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
              />
            </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
          </LayersControl>

          <GeoJSON data={PL.features} onEachFeature={onEachClick} ref={geoJsonRef}/>
          <GeoJSON data={WWD.features} onEachFeature={onEachClick} ref={geoJsonRef}/>
        </MapContainer>
      ),
      [],
    )
  
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  
    return (
      <div>
        {displayMap}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export { LeafletMap }
```

Comment: FYI - [eliminate these types for problems from your coding practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_—_dont_use_these)

Comment: could you provide the complete code snippet?

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks for the info! I tried to access the button with a const btn, but but it gave me the error: "btn is null"

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I updated the code block, but it is just a component, which I display inside one of my app tabs

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do `onClick={async () => await writeToClipboard(part, id)}`?

Comment: If I put: 
layer.bindPopup("Object ID: <b>" + part + "</b><br>Part ID: <b>" + id + "</b><br><button onClick={async () => await writeToClipboard(part, id)}>Copy to Clipboard</button>");   -     
The button inside the popup shows:
 await writeToClipboard(part, id)}>Copy to Clipboard